# JS Image onClick src problems

Tags: javascript, html

First post here.

So I am pretty good with my HTML and PHP, but fail at JS.
I am trying to make a simple toggle using images.

HTML:

```
<img src="clear.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()">
```

JS:

```
<script language="javascript">
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "clear.jpg") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "full.jpg";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "clear.jpg";
    }
}
```

This code does not work as the script is receiving the src as its full path and not just "clear.jpg".
Not a clue how to get around this.
I've tried using substr, that didn't work.
I wouldn't mind using the full path but the location could be relative on my server.

Rhys

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgClickAndChange = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");

if (imgClickAndChange.src.indexOf("clear.jpg") !== -1){
 imgClickAndChange.src="full.jpg"
}else{
 imgClickAndChange.src="clear.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have `clear.png` in your html snippet, but are checking for `clear.jpg` in your javascript. After you get that cleared up...

You can use the [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute) method to check for the "raw" contents of the attribute:

```
document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").getAttribute('src'); // clear.png
```

Or you can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), as @manraj82 suggests, to check if "clear.jpg" exists in  `imgClickAndChange`'s src property:

```
document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src.indexOf("clear.jpg") // numeric index of "clear.jpg" or -1 if not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression or `split` to get the section of the URL after the last `/` and compare that to the value you are testing against.

Alternatively, test with `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
function changeImage () {
    var img = document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange'),
        src = img.src;
    img.src = src.indexOf('clear') > -1 ? 'full.png' : 'clear.png';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jUXAf/).

Or:

```
function changeImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange'),
        src = img.src;

    img.src = src.replace(/(clear)|(full)/, function (a) {
        return a == 'clear' ? 'full' : 'clear';
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jUXAf/1/).

To make it a little more easily-extensible (allowing you to pass in any `img` element, and using an arbitrary length of images/URLs to toggle between):

```
function changeImage(el) {
    var self = el,
        src = self.src,
        toggleBetween = self.getAttribute('data-images').split(',');
    for (var i = 0, len = toggleBetween.length; i < len;  i++) {
        if (src.indexOf(toggleBetween[i]) > -1) {
            self.src = (i + 1 == len ? toggleBetween[0] : toggleBetween[i + 1]) + '.png';
        }
    }
}
```

Using the HTML:

```
<img src="clear.png" id="imgClickAndChange" data-images="clear,full,arbitrary,other,images" onclick="changeImage(this)" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jUXAf/3/).

And, finally, to remove the `onclick` event-handler, binding the event-handling in the script, rather than in the element itself to reduce the use of obtrusive (and difficult to maintain) JavaScript:

```
function changeImage(el) {
    var self = this,
        src = self.src,
        toggleBetween = self.getAttribute('data-images').split(',');
    for (var i = 0, len = toggleBetween.length; i < len;  i++) {
        if (src.indexOf(toggleBetween[i]) > -1) {
            self.src = (i + 1 == len ? toggleBetween[0] : toggleBetween[i + 1]) + '.png';
        }
    }
}

var elem = document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange');
elem.addEventListener('click', changeImage);

<img src="clear.png" id="imgClickAndChange" data-images="clear,full,arbitrary,other,images" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jUXAf/4/).

References:

- [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions).
- [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a flag to HtmlElement to store the state.

```
var img = document.getElementById('toggle_img');

img.onclick = function()
{
    img.src = img.isOff ? 'on.png' : 'off.png';

    img.isOff = !img.isOff;
}
```

See it in action on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RZsE/)